# Unable to connect JIRA Cloud

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

[image]I installed JIRA Cloud for sheet add-on. While connecting with JIRA instead of connecting using Atlassian account I used the google account and thus not get authenticated and got this error message.

Now the problem is, even if I try the the same again and wants to use Atlassian account, its still throwing the same error and not allowng me use Atlassian account. Cleared cache, reinstall JIRA Cloud for sheet add-on but no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you are still logged in with your google account into the Atlassian cloud Jira. 
Wonder how? Can you try opening id.atlassian.com? At the very left bottom corner, click on your profile pic and logout. Login again with your correct id and password and you should be able to use your Jira cloud as usual.

Remember, when you login into any Atlassian Cloud instance you actually login into id.atlassian.com account which is used for authentication by all other atlassian cloud sites. To logout completely, change account login you need to go to id.atlassian.com.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: No luck, I logged out at id.atlassian.com and changed password and tried again. Same error appearing. The issue was, I accidentally clicked at my google account to authenticate with Atlassian instead of standalone credentail for Atlassian. The authentication did not went through as expected but for some reason freezes there. I tried the way you advised, but getting the same error and when I see the error page it loads is https://api.atlassian.com/oauth2/authorize/consent?statexxxxxxxxxxxxx

Comment: Just to rule out cache problem completely, can you try in a different browser?